# groovy.lang$run.call(Unknown Source)

Tags: groovy

What is the meaning of groovy.lang$run.call(Unknown Source) and on what circumstances it will throw, this is the error what i'm getting in my groovy program

```
  at groovy.lang$run.call(Unknown Source)
  at groovy.lang.run(groovy.lang.Two_Script:6)

  ...................................................
  ...................................................
  at groovy.lang.run(groovy.lang.Two_Script:6)
at groovy.lang$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:121)
at one_script.run(level_one_script.groovy:5)
```

why it has not thrown at the compile time only @ runtime it has thrown any Idea ?

attached the sample groovy these are very simple recursive calls;

```
 level_one_script.groovy
        new Two_Script(binding).run()
    Two_Script.groovy
        new Three_Script().run()
    Three_Script.groovy
        println   "Anish"
```

the exception was thrown while evaluating Three_Script.groovy , it give me recurive call on Two_Script.groovy

```
Exception occurred while executing the script [level_one_script.groovy] - [java.lang.StackOverflowError].

try
{
compiledScript.eval(bindings)
//compiledScript is the type of CompiledScript
}
```

Surprising part is if i remove the call  new Three_Script().run() from "Two_Script.groovy" 
it shows me correct result

Surprising

```
 If the Groovy scripts are all defined in a package, the error is not thrown.
 If the scripts are moved to the default package (no package), the error is thrown.
```

Comment: In the part of the stack trace you show, there is a Level_Two_Script you did not mention while explainig the code. What does it do? Anyway, please post the first few lines of the stack trace as tim_yates says.

Comment: @just corrected my stacktrace

Comment: It's really hard to see an answer here, as it's really hard to see what you are doing and really hard to see how you are doing it...

Comment: If the Groovy scripts are all defined in a package, the error is not thrown. If the scripts are moved to the default package (no package), the error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual exception thrown (first few lines)

Looks like there's problem in your file `level_one_script.groovy` at line 5

Comment: attached the sample groovy scripts, it works fine with the command line , but throws some error while executing in my apps, need to understand the root cause of groovy.lang$run.call(Unknown Source)

Comment: The root cause will be in the stacktrace, just not in the small bit of the stacktrace you posted...  If you ignore all of the `groovy.lang.run` bits, what else does the stacktrace say?

Comment: @anish Also, maybe showing how you're running it might help?  These are the sorts of details you seem to always omit from your questions, and without them an answer is nearly impossible.

Comment: i'm still looking whats wrong in my code, but running standalone  why it's printing "Anish" while running level_one_script.groovy as Three_Script.groovy don't have any run method

Comment: @anish As I said, please post the first few lines of the stack trace, and how you are running it when it crashes